# Snapping to a segment of the point symbol (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, buffer, snapping, virtual-layer

I have a point layer in QGIS with an attribute field which represents a distance value. My goal is to generate a buffer with this distance value on the fly to which I can snap when creating another point.

- I don't want to use any processing tools because I want to snap to the segments in Qfield and/or MerginMaps
- I have tried different methods to create this buffer with the symbology. Using this method it is not possible to snap to the segments.

Background information:
When collecting data in the field with Qfield and MerginMaps using an RTK GNSS I want to be able to calculate indirect points with low GPS accuracy. So I would measure two points with the offset to be able to calculate the indirect point.

Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this using a virtual layer.

Go to the menu `Layer > Add Layer > Add/Edit Virtual Layer...` and enter the following query.

```sql
select st_buffer(geometry,dist) 
from myPointLayer
```

Snapping is then available at the intersection
[image]

Comment: Hi and thank you for your tip. I've tried it out but unfortunately the buffer is not shown. Have I missed anything?
(see screenshot on top)

Comment: Replace `Distanz` with a numerical value: the buffer's size. Replace `Disto` with the name of your point layer.

Comment: `Distanz` is the attribute field with the buffer value and `Disto` is the name of my point layer

Comment: ... started again from scratch and now it works perfectly. Dont't know what went wrong the first time. Anyway... thanks a lot for your effort, this helps a lot :-)

Comment: Done ;-) Thank you!